# UnsatisfiedLinkError - how to create the c++-DLL?

Tags: java, c++, dll, jna

I am trying to generate a dll which I can access from java via JNA.

I just try a simple one:

CPP:

```
void Initialize()
{
  std::cout<< "Hello World!";
}
```

iostream is also included and after compiling I get: CreateDll.dll

Via Visual Studio I can generate now a *.dll.

which I try loading into Java like:

```
public class mainRoutine {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    NativeWrapper INSTANCE = (NativeWrapper) Native.loadLibrary("CreateDll" , NativeWrapper.class);             
    INSTANCE.Initialize();
  }

  static {
    System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "C:\\workspace\\JNA");
  }
}
```

There is also another Interface:

import com.sun.jna.Library;

```
public interface NativeWrapper extends Library {
  void Initialize();
}
```

So but now running the Java function I get the error,

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
  Error looking up function 'Initialize': 
   The specified procedure could not be found.
```

What am I missing?

PS: I know there are many topics, but trying for a day already I have not found the solution. Please help me.

Comment: I'm guessing your DLL isn't exporting the required symbol.

Comment: Use dependency walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to view the exported function names.

Comment: If you're going to compile stuff anyway, [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) is probably easier to use than JNA...

Comment: Are you compiling on *nix or windows?

Comment: Nick: Correct (see below)
Technomage: Yeah probably was wrong function names.
Samuel: Ill check it out
Bitmap: On Windows.

Comment: @SamuelAudet: Taking your example code on your JavaCPP page and executing the commands in the shell returns: error: package com.googlecode.javacpp does not exist as well as for package com.googlecode.javacpp.annotation. Even though I am using your javacpp.jar. Has something changed?

Comment: No, nothing has changed. `javacpp.jar` probably isn't in your classpath...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to both export and (if using C++) un-decorate the function name.

On windows, functions are typically made available for export with `__declspec(dllexport)`.

On any platform, to ensure a function is exported in unmanagled form, you must use `extern "C"`.

Specifically:

```
extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) Initialize() { ... }
```

There are other ways to designate exported functions, but this is probably the most common and straightforward to use.  If you *don't* use `extern "C"`, your function will look something like `InitializeZ@ASDF@`, where the additional garbage characters are used by the compiler and linker to make a given function uniquely recognizable based on its calling signature.

Answer (score 0):

Are you exporting the symbol:

```
void _declspec(dllexport) Initialize()
{
  std::cout<< "Hello World!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if there is a class to be implemented ? where the .h file looks like this:

```
namespace simpleDLLNS
{
    class simpleDLL
    {
    public:

       char giveVoidPtrGetChar(void* param);
       int giveIntGetInt(int a);
       void simpleCall(void);
       int giveVoidPtrGetInt(void* param);
    };
}
```

Where should extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) be used ?
I used it when implementing the functions. but when i opened the dll, it looked like this:

?simpleCall@simpleDLL@simpleDLLNS@@QAEXXZ